# (LLDB on MacOs Catalina) Shell Expansion Failed

Tags: c, macos, debugging, lldb, macos-catalina

When trying to use the `r` or `run` commands in lldb I get an error like this: `error: shell expansion failed (reason: invalid JSON). consider launching with 'process launch'.`

It works when I just use `process launch` but I really do not feel like doing that.

Is there any way I could make either an alias or make shell expansions not fail?

Answer (score 1):

The way lldb does shell expansion is to run a little tool called `lldb-argdumper` (it is in Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources on macOS) with the command arguments that you passed.  `lldb-argdumper` wraps the contents of argv as JSON, and writes that to stdout.  lldb then parses the JSON back into args and inserts the args one by oneinto the argc/argv array when it launches the process.

Something in the output is not getting properly wrapped.  You can probably see what it is by looking at the output of `lldb-argdumper` with your arguments.  Whatever it is, it's a bug, so if you can reproduce it please file with your example with http://bugs.llvm.org.

```
(lldb) command alias run-no-shell process launch -X 0 --
```

will produce an alias that doesn't do shell expansion.  You can also put this in your ~/.lldbinit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently. TL;DR: make sure your shell does not echo anything during initialization. Run `<your-shell> -c date` to confirm; only the date should be printed.

The problem was that my shell's initialization file was echoing some stuff, which was getting prepended to `lldb-argdumper`'s JSON output. (`lldb` doesn't run `lldb-argdumper` directly; it invokes your default shell to run `lldb-argdumper`.)

Specifically, I use `fish` as my shell, which does not have separate initialization paths for interactive and non-interactive sessions. (See [this issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5394) for discussion of whether this is good.) `bash` and `zsh` have separate init files for interactive/non-interactive sessions, which makes avoiding this problem slightly easier.